# creating an iframe for a page

Tags: html, iframe

I have the url that i retrieve for an item and for each record i need to create an iframe to house them

Example

```
http://www.videoapt.com/tabid/53/VPID/119/VP/AMLI7thStreetStation/Default.aspx
```

how do i do this and whats the syntax for creating an iframe and does this iframe size to the url size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe name="myIframe" width="800" height="600" src="page.htm">
</iframe>
```

and then if you want to load pages in iframe, just do this:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="myIframe">Load Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy, if I understand your question right.

`<iframe src="(your long URL)" width="300" height="100">
</iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this resource: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

The IFrame will not automatically size to the URL.  You can set the height and width attributes though.

You'll probably want something like this:

```
    <iframe src ="http://www.videoapt.com/tabid/53/VPID/119/VP/AMLI7thStreetStation/Default.aspx 
" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto">
```